# Getting the error Ecto.Changeset.fetch/2 is undefined or private

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am attempting to make a simple sign in page. Whenever I try to route my page to the user sign up I am getting the following error.

```
UndefinedFunctionError at GET /users/new
function Ecto.Changeset.fetch/2 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:

      * fetch_change/2
      * fetch_field/2
```

This error seems to be coming from the Changeset as whenever I comment out my Changeset and just render an empty html page it works. Any help would be much appreciated.

web/controllers/user_controller.ex

```
defmodule Test.UserController do
  use Test.Web, :controller
  alias Test.User

  def new(conn, params) do
    changeset = User.changeset(%User{})
    render conn, "new.html", changeset   
  end

  def show(conn, %{"user_id_hash" => user_id_hash}) do
    render conn, "user_index.html", %{layout: {Test.LayoutView, "react.html"}}
  end

  def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    changeset = User.changeset(%User{}, user_params)
    case Repo.insert(changeset) do 
      {:ok, user} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "#{user.username} thank you for signing up please check your email to confirm your account.")
        |> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :index))
      {:error, changeset}->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end

end
```

Then for my model in web/models/user.ex

```
defmodule Test.User do
  use Test.Web, :model

  #Allows us to query the Database as Repo.
  alias Test.Repo
  #Allows us to use our User model as User.(function)
  alias Test.User

  #These are
  @fields ~w(username email password encrypted_password user_id_hash password_confirmation)a

  #These are the required fields as atoms for the validate_required method.
  @required_fields_atoms ~w(username email password password_confirmation)a

  schema "users" do
    field :username, :string
    field :email, :string
    field :encrypted_password, :string
    field :user_id_hash, :string
    field :account_confirmed, :boolean
    field :confirmation_hash, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    field :password_confirmation, :string, virtual: true
    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, @fields)
    |> validate_required(@required_fields)
    |> validate_length(:username, min: 6, max: 32)
    |> validate_length(:password, min: 8, max: 100)
    |> validate_confirmation(:password, message: "does not match password")
    |> put_pass_hash()
  end


  def generate_confirmation_token() do
    rand_string = random_string(26)
  end

  defp put_pass_hash(changeset) do
    case changeset do
      %Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true, changes: %{password: pass}} ->
        put_change(changeset, :encrypted_password, Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt(pass))
      _ -> changeset
    end
  end


  defp random_string(length) do
    :crypto.strong_rand_bytes(length) |> Base.url_encode64 |> binary_part(0, length)
  end

end
```

When running the program the error say it is coming from

```
Test.UserController.action/2 (test)
web/controllers/user_controller.ex (line 1)
```

I don't ever call a fetch function would be much obliged if somebody could help.

**EDIT** Added the stack trace

```
[error] #PID<0.365.0> running Test.Endpoint terminated
Server: my-name.c9users.io:8081 (http)
Request: GET /users/new
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Ecto.Changeset.fetch/2 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:

      * fetch_change/2
      * fetch_field/2

        (ecto) Ecto.Changeset.fetch(#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{}, errors: [username: {"can't be blank", []}], data: #Test.User<>, valid?: false>, :conn)
        (phoenix_html) lib/phoenix_html/engine.ex:98: Phoenix.HTML.Engine.fetch_assign/2
        (test) web/templates/layout/app.html.eex:11: Test.LayoutView."app.html"/1
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/view.ex:335: Phoenix.View.render_to_iodata/3
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/controller.ex:641: Phoenix.Controller.do_render/4
        (test) web/controllers/user_controller.ex:1: Test.UserController.action/2
        (test) web/controllers/user_controller.ex:1: Test.UserController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
        (test) lib/test/endpoint.ex:1: Test.Endpoint.instrument/4
        (test) lib/phoenix/router.ex:261: Test.Router.dispatch/2
        (test) web/router.ex:1: Test.Router.do_call/2
        (test) lib/test/endpoint.ex:1: Test.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
        (test) lib/plug/debugger.ex:93: Test.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (test) lib/test/endpoint.ex:1: Test.Endpoint.call/2
        (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
        (cowboy) src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
^C
```

Comment: Can you please add the exact stack trace printed by Elixir to the question?

Comment: @Dogbert, I have updated the question with the stack trace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `Test.UserController`, this:

```
render conn, "new.html", changeset
```

should be

```
render conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset
```

The weird error you're getting is because [Phoenix templates fetch `@` variables using `Dict.fetch`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_html/blob/660e6e92d0f890b32acf6c85a6765e27940f6fb8/lib/phoenix_html/engine.ex#L100). In this case, you're most likely using `@conn` somewhere in your template, and it's trying to run `Dict.fetch(changeset, :conn)`, which delegates to `changeset.__struct__.fetch(changeset, :conn)` as `changeset` is a struct, and ends up calling `Ecto.Changeset.fetch(changeset, :conn)`.

Comment: I met almost the same problem, and have been debugging for a hour without any findings --  you saved my day. Thank you!